# python regular expression get numbers except decimal

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the greater than or equal to 6 digit number, but ignore the decimal. For example:

```
123 => invalid
123456 => 123456
123456.12 => invalid
abcd1234567efg => 1234567
abcd1234567.123efg => invalid
```

How do I use python regular-expressions to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use negative/positive look ahead and alternation

`\d{6,}(?=\D)(?!\.)|\d{6,}(?=$)`

<kbd>[DEMO LIVE](https://regex101.com/r/wU1bZ7/2)</kbd>

Comment: but this failed: `abc123456`